# Proving that weird topology is compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

The following question appeared on my topology exam. I couldn't solve it then, and now I am trying it once again.

Could someone check my proof to see if it is correct, or maybe suggest an easier way?

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a topological Hausdorff space.

> Let $p\not\in X$ and define $\widehat{X}=X\cup\{p\}$ with the topology $\widehat{\mathcal{T}}$ (you may assume that this indeed defines a topology):
>
> $$U\in\widehat{\mathcal{T}}\iff\begin{cases}p\in U \text{ and }X\setminus U\text{ is a compact subset of }X,\text{ or} \\ p\not\in U\text{ and }U\in\mathcal{T}. \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $\widehat{X}$ is compact.

I drew a picture, where the red space is $X$ and the green circles are the open sets in the covering.

[image]

My approach:

Let $\{A_\alpha \}_{\alpha\in I}$ an open covering of $\widehat{X}$.

Let $J\subset I$ such that $p\in A_\alpha\iff \alpha\in J$. Take an $\alpha'\in J$. We know that $X\setminus A_{\alpha'}$ is a compact subset of $X$.

For all $\beta\in J$, $X\setminus A_\beta$ is compact. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, we now that $X\setminus A_\beta$ is closed, so $A_\beta\cap X$ ($=A_\beta\setminus\{p\}$) is open in $X$.

Now $\{A_\beta\setminus\{p\} \}_{\beta\in J}\cup \{A_\gamma \}_{\gamma\in I\setminus J}$ is an open covering of $X$ using open sets in $X$, so it also covers $X\setminus A_{\alpha'}$.

This implies that there exist $M\subset J$ and $N\subset I\setminus J$ finite such that $\{A_\beta\setminus\{p\} \}_{\beta\in M}\cup \{A_\gamma \}_{\gamma\in N}$ covers $X\setminus A_{\alpha'}$, or that

$$\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\{\alpha' \}\cup M\cup N}$$

is a finite subcovering of $\{A_\alpha \}_{\alpha\in I}$  of $\widehat{X}$.

Comment: FYI, this is the [one point compactification](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwim7biSqqXiAhXOMt4KHearCsQQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAlexandroff_extension&usg=AOvVaw2f6eSi_i6OUojHWeMg7EWC)

Comment: @YuiToCheng thanks, we did not discuss that in our course but that is what the professor was inspired by apparently :D

Comment: Aren't $all$ the $X\cap A_{\alpha}$ open in $X$ just by definition of the subspace topology?

Comment: I wrote out as an answer what I mean.

Comment: Known as  the one-point (or Alexandroff) compactification of $X$ when $X$ is not compact. A compactification is a continuous injective  $c:X\to Y$ where Y is compact and  the image $c(X)$ is dense in $Y$ and $c:X\to c(X)$ is a homeomorphism ( with $c(X)$ as a sub-space of $Y$). For short, a dense homeomorphic embedding of $X$ into $Y$. When discussing only one of these we can often take $c=id_X$ so $X=c(X)$ is a dense sub-space of $Y$. In the context of Tychonoff spaces it is common  that $Y$ is required to be Hausdorff, which requires $X$ to be Tychonoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subspace topology $X$ inherits from $\widehat X$ is the same as the original topology on $X:$

$\ U\in \tau_X\Rightarrow U\in \tau_{\widehat X}$, by definition. On the other hand, if $p\in U\in \tau_{\widehat X},\ $ then $X\cap U=X\setminus (X\setminus U)$ is open in $X$ because $X\setminus U$ is compact hence closed in $X$ (because $X$ is Hausdorff).

So, $\{X\cap A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is an open cover of $X$, hence of $X\setminus A_{\alpha'}.$  Therefore, there are integers $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ such that $\{X\cap A_{\alpha_i}\}^n_{i=1}$ covers $X\setminus A_{\alpha'}$ which implies that $\{A_{\alpha_1},\cdots, A_{\alpha_1}, A_{\alpha'}\}$ covers $\widehat X.$

Comment: I see the following problem: $X\setminus A_\alpha$ is a compact subset of $X$ and not of $\widehat{X}$, and $\{A_\alpha \}_{\alpha\in I}$ is not necessarily a covering with opens in $X$.

Comment: I don't think you established that $\{A_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in I}$ is an open cover of $X \backslash A_{\alpha}$ in the topology $\mathcal{T}$, so you can't immediately use compactness of $X \backslash A_{\alpha}$ in $X$ to get a finite subcover. The OP did exactly what you've done, but didn't skip this crucial step. Alternatively, one could note that $\mathcal{T}$ is the subspace topology of $X \subset \widehat{X}$ to conclude that $X \backslash A_\alpha$ is compact in $\widehat{X}$ as well.

Comment: I wrote out in more detail what I meant. It seems straightforward, but I may be missing something.

Comment: @jawheele thanks, your comment is exactly what I was after! Thanks Matematleta for verifying my proof! I was in doubt if I used some redundant steps, but now I understand :)